# How do I get an output schema for an Apache Beam SQL query?

Tags: sql, apache-beam, apache-calcite

I've been playing with the Beam SQL DSL and I'm unable to use the output from a query without providing a coder that's aware of the output schema manually. Can I infer the output schema rather than hardcoding it?

Neither the [walkthrough](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/walkthrough/) or the [examples](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/example/BeamSqlExample.java) actually use the output from a query. I'm using [Scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio) rather than the plain Java API to keep the code relatively readable and concise, I don't think that makes a difference for this question.

Here's an example of what I mean.

Given an input schema `inSchema` and some data source that is mapped onto a `Row` as follows: (in this example, Avro-based, but again, I don't think that matters):

```
sc.avroFile[Foo](args("input"))
   .map(fooToRow)
   .setCoder(inSchema.getRowCoder)
   .applyTransform(SqlTransform.query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PCOLLECTION"))
   .saveAsTextFile(args("output"))
```

Running this pipeline results in a `KryoException` as follows:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Serialization trace:
fieldIndices (org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema)
schema (org.apache.beam.sdk.values.RowWithStorage)
org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: 
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, inserting a `RowCoder` matching the SQL output, in this case a single count int column:

```
   ...snip...
   .applyTransform(SqlTransform.query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM PCOLLECTION"))
   .setCoder(Schema.builder().addInt64Field("count").build().getRowCoder)
   .saveAsTextFile(args("output"))
```

Now the pipeline runs just fine.

Having to manually tell the pipeline how to encode the SQL output seems unnecessary, given that we specify the input schema/coder(s) and a query. It seems to me that we should be able to infer the output schema from that - but I can't see how, other than maybe using Calcite directly?

Before raising a ticket on the Beam Jira, I thought I'd check I wasn't missing something obvious!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output schema inference [should work](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9319ce18ac625b239c8cdc1b32e2b697d83c2504/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/impl/rel/BeamCalcRel.java#L80), your expectation is correct. This seems like a bug (either in Beam or Scio), filed [BEAM-5335](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5335) for investigation.

Comment: I think it is a bug in Scio - the pipeline works in plain Java, as it turns out. Then I saw that Scio sets the coder itself after applying a transform, maybe this is the problem. I'll raise a ticket on the repo https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/e95310ec0828e60209e279baa5047a6b62288c5a/scio-core/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/values/SCollection.scala#L149

Comment: Thank you for following up! I'll update the Jira with your findings. I am not familiar with how Scio sets coders when expanding PTrasnforms but it does look like where the bug would live.

Comment: Overall, Beam SQL and Schemas are very much under active development and there can be bugs and breaking changes now and then. Plus to my knowledge neither Beam SQL nor Schemas are currently being explicitly tested against Scio, so there's extra layer of possible issues there.